# How can I send JSON to consumer using RabbitMQ and Elixir?

Tags: rabbitmq, elixir

I am trying to send JSON to consumer with RabbitMQ? Is it possible and how? I am using Elixir as my programming language.

Comment: Please see https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-elixir.html for the idea

Comment: Stackoverflow is better suited to getting answers to specific problems. Please try some things on your own, and come back if you have questions along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this link to : 
https://github.com/pma/amqp

Open issues to more information about send JSON.

```
iex(1)> {:ok, conn} = AMQP.Connection.open
{:ok, %AMQP.Connection{pid: #PID<0.364.0>}}
iex(2)> {:ok, chan} = AMQP.Channel.open(conn)
{:ok,
 %AMQP.Channel{conn: %AMQP.Connection{pid: #PID<0.364.0>}, pid: #PID<0.376.0>}}
iex(3)> AMQP.Queue.declare chan, "test_queue"
{:ok, %{consumer_count: 0, message_count: 0, queue: "test_queue"}}
iex(4)> AMQP.Exchange.declare chan, "test_exchange"
:ok
iex(5)> AMQP.Queue.bind chan, "test_queue", "test_exchange"
:ok
iex(6)> AMQP.Basic.publish(chan, "test_exchange", "", Poison.encode(%{ name: "S" }), [content_type: "application/json"])
:ok
```